# Aladdin eToken install issue on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, smartcard

Has anyone been able to get Aladdin eToken to work on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. COuld someone provide the steps for same.

Comment: I've got the same problems on Ubuntu 14.04. Tried different packages from default repo - nothing helped. Looks like the only solution would be write a letter to vendor. More letters from different users, higher chances that this issue will be fixed: http://www.aladdin-rd.ru/company/contacts/feedback

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is a SafeNet Client v9.0 released in Jan 2015, but it is not freely available. See [this post](http://data-protection-updates.safenet-inc.com/2015/01/30/safenet-authentication-client-sac-9-0-release-update/) on their website for more info. Please note that Aladdin Knowledge Systems Ltd. is now owned by SafeNet Inc.